# ES audio not working (Retropie)

Tags: audio, raspbian-buster, retropie, alsa, pixel

I'm running RetroPie on my Pi 4 4GB. I recently installed PIXEL through the RetroPie setup program, and now the sound doesn't work. If I exit ES and use `aplay` to play an audio file, it plays fine. But Emulation Station does not play sounds, and neither does RetroArch. When I exit, I see an error: `lvl0:  VolumeControl::init() - Failed to find mixer elements!` I have tried everything listed on the RetroPie Docs page, and it still doesn't work! Can someone please help me? I'm confused.